# Датафрейм считывается как словарь после добавления функций и библиотеки tkinter (pandas, tkinter)

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Написала код, который берет два файла, сравнивает их и выводит текстовый файл с различиями. В юпитере работает отлично. Для коллег, решила добавить блок из библиотеки tkinter, чтобы можно было в дальнейшем выгрузить как exe.
Проблема в том, что теперь я не могу сделать корректировку датафрейма перед "превращением" его в словарь. Ниже сокращенный код и ошибка:

Ошибка: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'columns'

```
def browse_file(file_entry):
...
def choose_sheet(file_path):
...
def choose_header(file_path):
...
def load_excel():
    file_path1 = entry1.get()
    file_path2 = entry2.get()
    sheet_name1 = choose_sheet(file_path1)
    sheet_name2 = choose_sheet(file_path2)
    header_1 = choose_header(file_path1)
    header_2 = choose_header(file_path2)
    LK = pd.read_excel(file_path1, sheet_name=sheet_name1,
                                 usecols=['Формы', 'Показатели'], 
                                 header=header_1)
    MANUAL = pd.read_excel(file_path2, sheet_name=sheet_name2,
                                usecols=['ID', 'FORM', 'HIDDEN', 'MSR'],
                                header=header_2)
    condition = MANUAL['MSR'] == 'MSR0050'
    MANUAL = MANUAL[~condition]

#блок со словарями
def dicts(MANUAL, LK):    
    result_dict_3 = {}
    for _, row in MANUAL.iterrows():
        keys = str(row['FORM']).replace('\n', '').split(',')
        value = row['ID']
        for key in keys:
            if key == 'nan':
                continue  # Пропустить 'nan'
            if key in result_dict_3:
                result_dict_3[key].add(value)
            else:
                result_dict_3[key] = {value}
.......
```

То есть, я загружаю файл, удаляю строки по условию и уже измененный файл хочу использовать как словарь. Но как бы я не меняла порядок функций, все равно ошибка, что файл MANUAL стал словарем, никак не уходит.